# Why is the homepage not scrolling

Tags: php, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple problem but I can't find the error:

My index.php includes per *switch* include1.php for "index.php?do=show". This in turn calls an object from objects.php which iterates over a mysql query and puts every item into a single  element. Although I have more items than my screen is able to show at once, I have no scrolling bar and it is not possible to scoll anyways. How can I fix it? Twitter Bootrstrap is the frontend framework.

Here the code which is used in the objects.php do display the mysql query:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {

    echo "
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='span4 showmoment'>".$row[0]."<br>
                <br>
                 - <I>created: ".$row[1]."</I> </div>
            </div><br>
            ";
}
```

showmoment is a class defined be me. The rest are bootstrap classes.

```
.showmoment {
-moz-border-radius:5px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius:5px; /* Safari, Chrome */
-khtml-border-radius:5px; /* Konqueror */
border-radius:5px; /* CSS3 */
background-color: #E6E6E6;
padding-top:20px;
padding-right:2px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-left:12px
}
```

**Solved:**

I solved the problem by finding that a closing `</div>` for  `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">` was missing. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Comment out your twitter bootstrap css and javascript includes. Does the problem still exist?

Comment: What's the element that's wrapping the `div.row`? Which direction scroll are you having problems? Vertical or horizontal?

Comment: can you show the context that `.showmoment` is used in (it's parent elements)?

Comment: @couzzi no it is scrollable when I comment out Bootstrap css.